# Encryption in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, encryption

I am looking to encrypt and decrypt the parameter of my the model id in my query string.  I have read several different methods of doing this, but some of the articles are a bit dated.  What is the best way to encrypt the querystring?

I have followed the method outlined in this article [http://www.dotnettrace.net/2013/09/encrypt-and-decrypt-url-in-mvc-4.html], also referenced in this SO question. [Encrypt Route Data in URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885975/asp-net-mvc-encrypt-route-data-in-url).

I have the encoded action link working, but I can't figure out how to use that same encrypted id in a redirection action in my controller.

Is the method that I am using the best method?  I want to prevent users from changing the ID in the querystring to see another record.

```
//extension
 public static MvcHtmlString EncodedActionLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues, object htmlAttributes)
    {
        string queryString = string.Empty;
        string htmlAttributesString = string.Empty;
        if (routeValues != null)
        {
            RouteValueDictionary d = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Keys.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    queryString += "?";
                }
                queryString += d.Keys.ElementAt(i) + "=" + d.Values.ElementAt(i);
            }
        }

        object newRouteValues = new { q = Encrypt(queryString) };

        string url = UrlHelper.GenerateUrl(null, actionName, controllerName, null, null, null, new RouteValueDictionary(newRouteValues), htmlHelper.RouteCollection, htmlHelper.ViewContext.RequestContext, true);
        TagBuilder tagBuilder = new TagBuilder("a")
        {
            InnerHtml = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linkText)) ? HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(linkText) : String.Empty
        };
        tagBuilder.MergeAttributes(HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes));
        tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url);

        return new MvcHtmlString(tagBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }


    private static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        string key = "@m2qJzeyjXLBK!axPV$Bvg3QUP";
        byte[] EncryptKey = { };
        byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
        EncryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] inputByte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cStream = new CryptoStream(mStream, des.CreateEncryptor(EncryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cStream.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);
        cStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(mStream.ToArray());
    }

//attribute
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class EncryptedActionParameterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        Dictionary<string, object> decryptedParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("q") != null)
        {
            string encryptedQueryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Get("q");
            string decrptedString = Decrypt(encryptedQueryString.ToString());
            string[] paramsArrs = decrptedString.Split('?');

            for (int i = 0; i < paramsArrs.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] paramArr = paramsArrs[i].Split('=');
                decryptedParameters.Add(paramArr[0], Convert.ToInt32(paramArr[1]));
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < decryptedParameters.Count; i++)
        {
            filterContext.ActionParameters[decryptedParameters.Keys.ElementAt(i)] = decryptedParameters.Values.ElementAt(i);
        }
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    }

    private string Decrypt(string encryptedText)
    {
        string key = "@m2qJzeyjXLBK!axPV$Bvg3QUP";
        byte[] DecryptKey = { };
        byte[] IV = { 55, 34, 87, 64, 87, 195, 54, 21 };
        byte[] inputByte = new byte[encryptedText.Length];

        DecryptKey = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key.Substring(0, 8));
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        inputByte = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedText);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(DecryptKey, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(inputByte, 0, inputByte.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        System.Text.Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
}
```

This EncodedActionLink is working as expected:

```
@Html.EncodedActionLink("Add Log", "CreateLog", "Logs", new { id = Model.id }, new { @class = "btn btn-success btn-xs" })
```

How do I encrypt the id in the controller?

```
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Log", new { id = ENCRYPTEDIDHERE})
```

UPDATE ===

I should add the the id is not the User ID.  The controller is already checking to see if the user is logged in and has the access to view the call log records.

Comment: Have you considered that, even if a user were able to guess the id for a resource belonging to another user, the system should check that the user should have access to that resource and return a `403` (or `404`, or whatever code you deem is appropriate) if they should not have access? This is to mitigate insecure direct object reference attacks https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A4-Insecure_Direct_Object_References

Comment: Why? (anyone can enter what ever they want in the address bar). If the user does not have permissions to access the item with that ID, just throw an error.

Comment: Encryption is mostly pointless there - just non-guessable, non-sequential ID (like Guid) should provide equivalent protection at much lower cost/complexity. The rest should be done with proper authentication/authorization like as suggesting [cacho's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32061681/477420)

Comment: Valid points.  Maybe I am just overcomplicating the matter.  I already have my roles in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that an Access List could be a nice solution here.

If you are encrypting the URL is security through obscurity, meaning that if someone steals the URL string id will still be able to see the page.

Think about the ACL approach, for instance, every user could have an Edit Profile Page `/profile/user/{id}`, and what you can do is use the ACL to check if the `{id}` is equals to the user id.

If the user is authorized, then return the content of the page. Otherwise, return an [HTTP Status 403 - Forbidden](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Check this link for ACL information in ASP .NET MVC:

[Where to add the ACL handler in the MVC Architecture.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/229571/where-should-the-acl-handler-be-called-in-a-mvc-architecture)

Comment: The id is not that of the user.  It the id of of call log record in the database

Comment: that's just an example. The ID could be anything. The key thing for building an ACL is this -> "ID X has(or does not have) permission over a given object Y"

Comment: Based on how I setup my roles, the same user who has access to say, id 4, will also have access to id 5.  I just don't want to make it easy for them to hop around records by changing the query string.

Comment: Then give permission to the user to ID 4, and 5. You don't need to have a 1 - 1 relationship in an ACL.

Comment: if you just want to make a little more difficult to iterate over your ID's (1,2,3,4,5,6), then you could create a random UUID. If that's secure enough for you it should be fine. I specify 'a little'  because someone can always try to guess your UUID.....

Comment: UUID/Guid is easier solution with comparable security. It will take *a bit* longer to guess correct GUID compared to int :)